# SKLabelNode sequence animation with unwanted delay inbetween

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction, sklabelnode

I have SKLabelNode representing current score, which I'm trying to animate with growing and shrinking sequence, whenever score value hits some particular number(e.g. 10, 20, ...). Problem is that animation itself has some sort of delay inbetween and takes far more time than duration I've set. Basically it grows, then it waits and after while finally shrinks back.

Here's my code:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        ...
        //skactions setting
        growAction = SKAction.scaleBy(1.2, duration: 0.4)
        shrinkAction = SKAction.scaleBy(0.8333, duration: 0.4)
        growAndShrink = SKAction.sequence([growAction, shrinkAction])
        ...
}


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */

        if (score % 10) == 0 && score != 0 && gameState == GameState.Play {
            scoreLabel.runAction(growAndShrink)
        }       
}
```

I though update func is the right one to use for that, or is it?

Comment: as long as the conditions remain true, which i assume will be the case for at least a couple frames, you will run the sequence. So you have several sequences running simultaneously, overwriting each other's scale modifications

Comment: true, so I need to add some sort of flag for that condition to ensure that only one sequence at a time can be run, or is there better solution?

Comment: yes, or even better: run this check in the method where the score variable is changed

Comment: finaly I was able to try it, and indeed running it at the same place as when score is changed is the best and easiest solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `completion:` argument here to make a call to the function that checks, whether the action should be re-run, e.g.

```
scoreLabel.runAction(growAndShrink, completion: { self.runAgain() })
```

`runAgain` would then contain your logic for checking and re-running the action. Basically you can combine both:

```
func runGrowAndShrinkAction()
{
    if (conditions)
    {
        scoreLabel.runAction(growAndShrink, completion: { self.runGrowAndShrinkAction() })
    }
}
```

Sidenote: if you use `runBlock` in your sequence, please consider, that it is called asynchronously. That is, the execution of `completion:` does not wait for the `runBlock` being finished.

**Update:** another option is to use `SKAction.repeatActionForever()` and if the conditions in your `update` method change, you can remove the action with `removeActionForKey()`.

Comment: Looks promising, I'm not able to try it at the moment, will keep you posted, thanks

Comment: Please also have a look at my updated answer. The second approach might be easier to implement and more safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `didSet property observer` on score to update the score label dynamically and perform the animation.

```
var score : Int = 0 {
    didSet
    {
        scoreLabel.text = "Score : \(score)"

        if (score % 10 == 0 && score != 0 && gameState == GameState.Play)
        {
            animateScore()
        }
    }
}

func animateScore()
{
    scoreLabel.removeAllActions()
    scoreLabel.text = "Score : \(score)"
    let growAction = SKAction.scaleBy(1.2, duration: 0.4)
    let shrinkAction = SKAction.scaleBy(0.8333, duration: 0.4)
    let growAndShrink = SKAction.sequence([growAction, shrinkAction])
    scoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(growAndShrink, count: 2))
}
```